# how can I remove attr in angular selector

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomp'})
```

and it will become:

```
<mycomp title='xxx'>
...my component content
<mycomp>
```

When I hover on the component, window will display the title content. How can I remove or change the title attr in selector? Or any way to close the title display when I hover?

Comment: I don't think that the Angular component will auto populate/add the `title` attribute. Check whether did you add it manually or any directive that will add the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the two methods work for me:

1. add a empty title so window will not display the content

```
<mycomp title='xxx'>
<my component content title=''>
<mycomp>
```

2. use ElementRef.nativeElement to change the attr